# Problem with handling Browser Cookies in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Well, I have a problem with a plugin handling browser cookies in vue.js

I installed plugin and imported it in main.js. I configured it too like below:

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import { createPinia } from "pinia";
import { globalCookiesConfig } from "vue3-cookies";

import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import { useMainStore } from "@/stores/main.js";
import { useStyleStore } from "@/stores/style.js";
import { darkModeKey, styleKey } from "@/config.js";
import "./css/main.css";

globalCookiesConfig({
  expireTimes: "30d",
  path: "/",
  domain: "",
  secure: true,
  sameSite: "None",
});
/* Init Pinia */
const pinia = createPinia();

/* Create Vue app */
createApp(App).use(router).use(pinia).mount("#app");


/* Init Pinia stores */
const mainStore = useMainStore(pinia);
const styleStore = useStyleStore(pinia);

/* Fetch sample data */
mainStore.fetch("clients");
mainStore.fetch("history");

/* App style */
styleStore.setStyle(localStorage[styleKey] ?? "basic");

/* Dark mode */
if (
  (!localStorage[darkModeKey] &&
    window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches) ||
  localStorage[darkModeKey] === "1"
) {
  styleStore.setDarkMode(true);
}

/* Default title tag */
const defaultDocumentTitle = "SOFT-KOMP";

/* Set document title from route meta */
router.afterEach((to) => {
  document.title = to.meta?.title
    ? `${to.meta.title} — ${defaultDocumentTitle}`
    : defaultDocumentTitle;
});
```

And In my LoginView.vue i inserted this line in function:
this.$cookies.set('hover-time','1s');
Unfortunately I receive this:

```
runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:218 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$cookies')
```

So this is my LoginView.vue file. And I tried to test some of other sessions and cookie plugins but results was always the same. PRobably Im not installing this plugin properly in the component or something?

```
<script setup>
import { reactive } from "vue";
import { useRouter } from "vue-router";
import { mdiAccount, mdiAsterisk } from "@mdi/js";
import SectionFullScreen from "@/components/SectionFullScreen.vue";
import CardBox from "@/components/CardBox.vue";
import FormCheckRadio from "@/components/FormCheckRadio.vue";
import FormField from "@/components/FormField.vue";
import FormControl from "@/components/FormControl.vue";
import BaseButton from "@/components/BaseButton.vue";
import BaseButtons from "@/components/BaseButtons.vue";
import LayoutGuest from "@/layouts/LayoutGuest.vue";

const form = reactive({
  login: "john.doe",
  pass: "highly-secure-password-fYjUw-",
  remember: true,
});

const router = useRouter();

const submit = () => {
  router.push("/dashboard");
};
const login = () =>{
  this.$cookies.set('hover-time','1s');
}
</script>

<template>
  <LayoutGuest>
    <SectionFullScreen v-slot="{ cardClass }" bg="purplePink">
      <CardBox :class="cardClass" is-form @submit.prevent="submit">
        <FormField label="Login" help="Please enter your login">
          <FormControl
            v-model="form.login"
            :icon="mdiAccount"
            name="login"
            autocomplete="username"
          />
        </FormField>

        <FormField label="Password" help="Please enter your password">
          <FormControl
            v-model="form.pass"
            :icon="mdiAsterisk"
            type="password"
            name="password"
            autocomplete="current-password"
          />
        </FormField>

        <FormCheckRadio
          v-model="form.remember"
          name="remember"
          label="Remember"
          :input-value="true"
        />

        <template #footer>
          <BaseButtons>
            <BaseButton @click='login' type="submit" color="info" label="Login" />
            <BaseButton to="/dashboard" color="info" outline label="Back" />
          </BaseButtons>
        </template>
      </CardBox>
    </SectionFullScreen>
  </LayoutGuest>
</template>
```

Comment: Can you show the LoginView.vue code?

Comment: @Fanoflix I did. Please check!

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you have to is, first import the use in your setup in your LoginView.vue: 
`import { useCookies } from "vue3-cookies";` 
Then you can use it like this:

```
const { cookies } = useCookies();
```

and then `cookies` is accessible across your setup. 
See answer and comment if you need more info.

Comment: I have a problem. I added this import and declared const cookies but when I try to set cookies like this:
  cookies.set("myCoookie", "abcdefg");
Its written: cookies.set is not a function

Comment: please console.log(cookies) here.

Comment: {
    "cookies": {
        "current_default_config": {
            "expireTimes": "30d",
            "path": "/",
            "domain": "",
            "secure": true,
            "sameSite": "None"
        }
    }
}

Comment: IT seems like my config from main.js is working properly but in component it cant recognize function of object cookies.
I cant use cookies.get, cookies.set

Comment: Sorry for late, use useCookie from VueUse, or set cookie directly using Cookies SPEC(more info on MDN)